# Script to change photos folder hierarchy

Tags: bash, ssh, synology

I'm looking for a script to change an existing folder structure quickly on my synology nas using ssh from YYYY/MM/DD/ to YYYY-MM-DD/ so nested to flat but struggling to find one or any examples probably due to me not searching for the correct terminology.

I did start to use exiftool and go through moving each item but the collection is taking ages.

for example an image01 that currently resides in say 2020/01/01/images01.jpg needs to move to 2020-01-01/images.jpg

image and video files only currently live in the day folders.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can do this with this command:

```
find . -mindepth 3 -type d |awk -F"/" 'system("mv " $2"/"$3"/"$4" "$2"-"$3"-"$4" && rmdir "$2"/"$3" && rmdir "$2" 2>/dev/null")'
```

Example input folder structure:

```
./2020/06/12/img1.jpg
./2020/06/12/file2.mpg
./2020/05/10/img2.jpg
./2020/05/10/img1.jpg
```

Result:

```
./2020-05-10/img1.jpg
./2020-05-10/img2.jpg
./2020-06-12/img1.jpg
./2020-06-12/file2.mpg
```

Explanation:

```
find . searches in the current directory
-mindepth 3 only searches at level 3 nesting
-type d only search for directories
| creates a pipe, directing the find result to AWK
-F"/" sets the AWK field separator to /
system command is executed for each line which transfers files to the new directory and deletes unnecessary old directories
&& do next command only when previous ones were successful
2>/dev/null directs stderr to the void so that you won't see any errors trying to delete a non-empty "year" directory
```

You cannot use rm -rf because the year directory may still contain other directories, hence using rmdir twice.

You can resolve the stderr redirection more elegantly by testing whether the directory of the year is empty before deleting it,
I do not put this test so as not to obscure the idea of ​​action unnecessarily.